# Why does my chrome extension returns blank canvas?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, html5-canvas, drawimage

The content script is fairly simple:
send all images and change there source from the background script answer:

```
let imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(let img of imgs){
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({imgsrc:img.src,imgw:img.width,imgh:img.height}, function(response) {
    img.src = response.canvasurl;
  });
}
```

The background script is simple too:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        async function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
            let tmp_img = document.createElement("img");
            tmp_img.width = request.imgw;
            tmp_img.height = request.imgh;
            tmp_img.src = request.imgsrc;
            let canvas = document.createElement("CANVAS");
            let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            canvas.width = request.imgw;
            canvas.height = request.imgh;
            ctx.drawImage(tmp_img, 0, 0);
            sendResponse({canvasurl: canvas.toDataURL()});
        });
```

But it just blank out all images (the canvas URL that is returned is empty canvas).
Any idea what is happening?

Comment: Image loads asynchronously, you need to listen to Image `load` event and then call `ctx.drawImage`

Comment: you are right (i also had to remove the async return in this function true and call to another function) thanks

Answer (score 1):

As  Michael Radionov pointed out i had to let the images load first but that was not enough
I also had to change it to this format:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
          all_of_the_async_logic(request,sendResponse);
          return true;
        });
```

that way i could tell the connection to wait for response (using return true and dropping the async in the listener)